# Как посмотреть в Android Studio сколько времени ушло на проект?

Tags: android

Собственно вопрос в заголовке. Есть ли такая возможность посмотреть сколько времени в общем потратилось на отдельный проект?

Comment: плагин подключить тайм-трекер

Comment: [ManicTime](https://www.manictime.com/), можно по заголовку программы фильтровать, вы же не только в студии что-то делаете когда разрабатываете.

Comment: Значит студия не отслеживает время? Только сторонними способами?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В AndroidStudio нет своего TimeTracker, я бы рекомендовал использовать https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7425-wakatime он будет использовать подсчет потраченного времени для каждого проекта и у него ещё огромное количество фич, проект хорошо поддерживается и рекомендован для AndroidStuido командой JetBrains. Подключается очень легко как плагин, все в ссылке.